# Session variables don't get passed to the third page after session start

Tags: session-variables, php

after starting a new session in my login.php i rediredct to home.php and load session variables successfully.But when i try to open menu.php from home.php and use session variables , those same variables are unndefined now. I echoed the session id after both page changes and its exactly the same. So can anyone please tell me why am i losing these variables?

login.php:

```
session_start();
 $_SESSION["user"]=$puser;
 $_SESSION["loggedin"]=true;
 echo "<script>window.open('../home.php','_self')</script>";
```

?>

home.php

```
require("php/objects.php");
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"]==true)
{
    $user=$_SESSION["user"];
    $_SESSION["loggedin"]=true;
    echo session_id();
    echo $_SESSION["loggedin"];
}
else
{
    echo "Login Error";
    echo "<script>window.open('default.html','_self')</script>";
    exit();
}``
```

?>

menu.php

```
require("objects.php");
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo $_SESSION["loggedin"];
/*if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"]==true)
{
    $user=$_SESSION["user"];
    $utype=isset($user->salary)?"staff":"client";

}
else
{
    echo "Login Error";
    echo "<script>window.open('../default.html','_self')</script>";
    exit();
}*/``
```

?>

when i click a link in home.php with href=menu.php i get an error that index loggedin is undefined

Comment: silly thing to check: did you `session_start()` in that 3rd script?

Comment: ...before outputting anything?

Comment: Show us the several first lines of each file. Also when you said "open menu.php from home.php" did you mean include or redirect as in first example?

Comment: Doesnt seem like a common issue. A little snippet of you code could help..

Comment: In the either test you use `http` or not?

Comment: my apolozies for not putting the code

Comment: What does `objects.php` contain?

Comment: it contains classes defining client and staff classes

Comment: Could you please try menu.php after commenting out `require("objects.php");`

Comment: If it works when `require("objects.php");` is commented out, it is possible that some characters is being output by the objects.php( it could be even a white space or a next line outside the php block ) that cause the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is in your objects.php, calling session should probably come before that.

```
session_start();
require("objects.php");
echo session_id();
echo $_SESSION["loggedin"];
```